# Custom Web Service in vti_bin folder does not show Service description

Tags: web-services, asp.net, wsdl

I've used the [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx#Y2500) from MSDN to create my cusom WCF Service and deploy to my Sharepoint 2010 server.

`http://myserver/_vti_bin/randomchatwebservice.asmx` seems to work fine and it shows service methods. But I get "The webpage cannot be found" when I try to reach `http://myserver/_vti_bin/randomchatwebservice.asmx?wsdl` or `http://myserver/_vti_bin/randomchatwebservice.asmx?disco`.

I have RandomChatWebServicedisco.aspx and RandomChatWebServicewsdl in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI` and spdisco.aspx file has

```
<contractRef
  ref=<% SPHttpUtility.AddQuote(SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(
         spWeb.Url + "/_vti_bin/RandomChatWebService.asmx?wsdl"),
         Response.Output); %>
  docRef=<% SPHttpUtility.AddQuote(SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(
            spWeb.Url + "/_vti_bin/RandomChatWebService.asmx"),
            Response.Output); %>
  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/" />
<discoveryRef
   ref=<% SPHttpUtility.AddQuote(SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(
          spWeb.Url + "/_vti_bin/RandomChatWebService.asmx?disco"),
          Response.Output); %>
  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/" />
```

definitions. What seems to be wrong?

Comment: if you answered yourself to the question, please don't edit your post, but add an answer. You will be able to mark as answer in few days, and the question will appear solved in the pages of the site

Comment: guys did anyone find a solution for the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Melih Öztürk posted a solution to his own question:

> contactRef part of the WSDL file seems to be not well-formed. I changed it and problem solved.

<sub>I'm posting this as a community wiki since this question seems to be abandoned. If anyone has more information, feel free to add it!</sub>

Comment: please explian what u did..even i am facing same issue..

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any more information. The only lead that @Melih posted was to check the WSDL.

Comment: Kit did you solve the issue?

Comment: @MelihÖztürk Er... I'm pretty sure you said that you had solved this issue when you edited it into your question. I just moved it into this answer.

Comment: So, I just asked the question to wrong person:) @jenny, did you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to deploy the custom web service to the Layouts (_layouts) folder rather than the ISAPI (_vti_bin) folder. All the issues with the disco and wsdl generation go away.

I posted a walkthough for this on my blog, [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET (ASMX) Web Service in SharePoint 2010](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Hi Rob, Can you access SPContext when you add the service to _layouts folder?

Comment: Yes. See my walkthrough for an example

Comment: So what is the main differences between deploying custom web service to _layouts and _vti_bin folders? I thought that accessing SPContext object differs on these selection.